# compass sass background image spirtes positioning

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have a country selector `UL>LI` list, and within this I have `span`'s with the country name, set to `display: block`.

What I'm doing is adding the class of `.icon-name` to this span, with the hope of the flag being aligned to the right of this span, but it's by default going to the left.

How do I change the background position of the bg image of the sprite to be `top right`?

Unfortunately, it's quite hard to know what cod eto provide as the compass sprite generator is a bit complicated, but I've copied some html and CSS that will hopefully give you a better idea:

http://jsfiddle.net/sxpWS/1/

```
    <ul>
        <li data-val="country-US"><a href="#country-US"><i class="icon-right-open-big"></i><span class="flags-US">UNITED STATES</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: please post the relevant css and html here and if possible provide a demo of the problem. This is too less information to help you.

Comment: Just updated my question.

Comment: You don't need to change the sprite. You need to alter the position of the item using the sprite. From your example I'd think the Flag will directly follow after the `<i>`

Comment: Thanks Nico - I don't think i understand, what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: flags-US should contain the flag icon you want and nothing more. So you just have to place this `<span>` to where you want it to be. Try to add `display: inline-block` instead of `block` and also remove floating if you set it on it. Like this the `<span>` with the icon should be next to your `.open-big` element.